# Build Configuration and Start Arguments

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, buildconfiguration

Will the value entered in "command line arguments" under start options be actually passed on as command line arguments to the executable in the release configuration or is it only a debug thing.

The question is, will it be part of the executable when deployed?

[image]

which ends up in the csproj file as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartArguments>-blah</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <StartArguments>-blah</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: @alexei Levenkov, I know it is passed on in the debug mode. How can I ascertain if it actually does in the release mode

Comment: You could output the arguments received in the Main method so that you can verify. Is your question whether the arguments will be received by the standalone EXE when launched by the user, or whether the arguments will be received by the EXE as it's compiled and run using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes Llama, my question is will the arguments be received by the standalone EXE when launched by the user

Comment: No, they will not be part of your application when you build it and give it to a user to run.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. Thank you Llama

Comment: @Llama, if you can add your comment as a reply, I will accept it as an answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#command-line-arguments)

The official documentation has a detailed introduction to this.

You can also use Environment.CommandLine or Environment.GetCommandLineArgs to access the command-line arguments from any point in a console or Windows Forms application.

### Demo：

[image]

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2 {
    internal class Program {
        static void Main (string[] args) {
            if (args.Length == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument.");
            else
                foreach (string arg in args)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(arg);
                    }
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

### exe:

When running independently: the following output：

[image]

### " They will not be part of your application when you build it and give it to a user to run." Llama is right.